# Convert frustum to a projection matrix in Java 3d

Tags: java, java-3d

I need to prepare for my exam and this is the probable question for the test. Given a frustum method such as frustum(-1,1, -0.5, 0.5, 1, 2) how to convert this to a projection matrix? The above example from my textbook but the writers don't define it in detail. If anyone can explain this in detail, I'd appreciate very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the documenation: [http://download.java.net/.../ViewModel.html](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.2/javax/media/j3d/doc-files/ViewModel.html) *(at the bottom)*